# How to combine 2 encodings

Tags: c#, chat

I am using a Node.js chat server which sends ASCII messages containing the id of the users and unicode (utf16 - little endian) messages as text messages. How can I determine the type of encoding in the C# client?

Comment: Is this "mixed encoding" in the same string? Or how does the object you get look like?

Comment: Are you using `HttpClient`? Can we see some code that you've tried?

Comment: Why do you care? What do you mean by "unicode"? Is it UTF8? ASCII is a subset of Unicode and UTF8 anyway so there should be no problem. What is the motive behind this question?

Answer (score 0):

Any given ASCII character has the same values in Unicode (if you're using UTF8). So the only way to know this is if one of the message characters is not an ASCII character.

A better way to figure this out is using a flag (either a bit, a character or multiple characters) that indicates whether something is a user id or a text message.